# Average out two values of variable byte-length together

Tags: c#, .net, performance, bit-manipulation

I'm writing a C# method that needs to average out two values together. However, the input is in the form of a byte array, and a value indicating the byte-length of a single value. The byte array contains two of these values. I'm trying to make the code performant, but I can't find anything.

A naive, slow solution:

```cs
public static long Average(byte[] values, int valueSize)
{
    byte[] first = values.Take(valueSize).ToArray();
    byte[] second = values.Skip(valueSize).Take(valueSize).ToArray();
    Array.Resize<byte>(ref first, sizeof(long));
    Array.Resize<byte>(ref second, sizeof(long));

    long firstValue = BitConverter.ToInt64(first, 0);
    long secondValue = BitConverter.ToInt64(second, 0);
    return (firstValue + secondValue) / 2;
}
```

(run online: https://onlinegdb.com/gBOofK_Kf)

Is there any way to improve the performance of this?

Comment: what if it has more bits than a long?

Comment: What are the restrictions on `valueSize`? Are the values MSB first or LSB first? Note that `Take` on a `byte[]` will take bytes, but you said `valueSize` is in bits? Also, `Take` and `Skip` are terribly inefficient ways to process an array.

Comment: Read it to a long then shift and mask it for your values?

Comment: Are the values on a byte boundary or are they packed next to each other, with one byte potentially split between two values?

Comment: @Hogan That shouldn't really occur (values >64bit aren't documented in the specification I'm using), but it would be nice if it had that functionality - unfortunately, I had no idea how to implement that without a high performance hit

Comment: @NetMage valueSize <= sizeof(long), so less or equal to 8

Comment: @harold Well, while writing the question, I tried to simplify it as much as possible, but internally, a large array is used to hold the values, so I feel like using an array as an input with the offset would be used in the actual implementation

Comment: @NetMage The values are always right next to each other without anything in between them, like `0x01 0x42 0x15 0x64` for a `valueSize = 2`

Comment: If this is never going to be bigger than an unsigned long then why aren't you just using unsigned long?  If you want it to be dynamic and of ANY size then you should use an existing infinite integer library where they have solved these problems.  There is one included in C# called BigInteger.  Just use that.

Comment: So did you mean to say `valueSize` is the *byte* length of a single value, and not the bit length?

Comment: @NetMage Oops, yeah, sorry about that! Gonna change that now.

Comment: @Hogan I'm aware of the existence of BigInteger, however I'm worried about the performance implications of using one. It looks like it uses a byte-array of unsigned ints and a seperate int to store the sign. I would use an unsigned long for all operations, but unfortunately, I do not have control over what data is going to be passed. I'm operating on PCM data, and sometimes, the data is either 8-bit, 16-bit, or 32-bit.

Comment: oh I see.  I think the best way is to make sure you always convert to 32 bit before you store.  Then every operation on the data will be native.   Having 3 formats in the same spot will just cause performance issues and complications.  Better to normalize when you first get the data.

Comment: @boooba Is the data in the byte array signed or unsigned? I assume it is always unsigned, but if it is signed then you can't use longs like in the example you provided.

Comment: @Petrusion I'm working on PCM data, so the convention is that if it's 8-bit, the data is unsigned, and anything else is signed. But the specification does allow for unsigned/signed data to be passed with any byte-length...

Comment: If this is for PCM data, in my opinion, it shouldn't work like this with a variable size to begin with. There are *a few* different possible sizes, implement them each individually (which makes them each trivial), then call the right one.

Comment: @harold When it comes to .WAV or RIFF data - that's true, but when working with audio hardware on a low-level, they support pretty much any audio data imaginable. For instance, the SoundBlaster 16 accepts both unsigned and signed 8-bit, and vice-versa for 16-bit. I'm trying to design this so it's as extensible as possible, but I *may* be overthinking this...

Comment: That's still only a handful of formats to support, and they're easier to support individually than they would be taken together in a function that is supposed to implement all of them at once (I'll note that the code above so far ignores the existence of signed formats, which would be mildly annoying to support with a `bool signed` parameter, but trivial when implemented individually)

Comment: @boooba You should have mentioned the data could be signed. For example, if you use the method you provided to try to average out two 4 byte wide numbers -1 and -3, you won't get -2 but 4294967294

Comment: I won't say that extensibility is bad, but in this case it's going to make the solution both more complicated and less efficient, so it's just not great. BTW with individually implemented formats you could even use [SIMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.sse2?view=net-6.0) to get nearly-native performance.

Comment: @harold You may be right, I've just looked up the specifications for the Intel HDA (https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-specifications/high-definition-audio-specification.pdf) and even that whole specification only supports samples up to 32-bit. I was afraid to implement it into multiple methods because of extensibility, but now I think that a multi-method solution would be more performant.